# PHP publishing JavaScript 

Tags: php, javascript

I have a PHP script that publishes customised JavaScript based on the parameter, with header type as `text/javascript`. This PHP URL is included in the `src` of a `<script>` tag. However, there seem to be an issue, because the script seems to be nonfunctional. As in, I have an alert inside the script, which should be executed immediately after inclusion, but it's not happening. Where am I going wrong?

**Server Side PHP**

```
<?php
//Exploding the path after the file widget to get user details
$expl = explode("/",$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']);
$c=count($expl);

//Handling the cases as widget/a widget//a etc 
switch($c) {
    case 2:
        if(empty($expl[0]) && !(empty($expl[1]))) pumpValid();
        else pumpInvalid();
        break;
    case 3:
        if(empty($expl[2]) && !(empty($expl[1])) && empty($expl[0])) pumpValid();
        else pumpInvalid();
        break;
    default:
        pumpInvalid();
        break;
}


function pumpValid() {
    global $expl;
    //Checking for a matching account in the urllist
    include('embedUrl/urllist.php');
    if(isset($customerList[$expl[1]])) {
        header("Content-Type: text/javascript");
        //Setting the host path  for fetching the JS files later. As in stage or vidteq.com
        echo "alert('h');";
        echo 'var _serverHostUrl="http://'.$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].eregi_replace('widget.*','',$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]).'";';
    }
    else
        pumpInvalid();
}

function pumpInvalid() {
    //Should redirect to error/home page
    echo "Are You Nuts";
}
?>

function init() {
    alert('hi');    
    addJSinHead('jquery-1.3.2.min.js');
    addJSinHead('OpenLayers.js');
    addJSinHead('json2.js');
    addJSinHead('dom-drag.js');
    addJSinHead('globals.js');
}

function addJSinHead(fileName) {
    var head=document.getElementsByTagName('head');
    var new=document.createElement('scrpit');
    new.src=_serverHostUrl+'/js'+fileName;
    new.type='text/javascript';
    head.appendChild(new);
}

init();
```

**Inclusion in client side HTML**

```
<script src='http://rak/cvs/widget/cis/' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the alert that should be executed inside of a function block? If so then you first need to execute the actual function.

Also try copying and pasting the javascript src url directly into the browser's url bar.

If the above didn't help, some code to analyze would be useful.

Comment: The alert is outside the function , so should be executed immediately. I have attached the code in question

Answer (score 0):

You can check with Firebug to see if the output of the script is what you expect and that the headers are being sent as you expect.

You'll need to provide some code for further help.

**EDIT:**
I don't see anywhere that you output a header in php:

```
 header('Content-Type: text/javascript');
```

**EDIT2:**
It looks like you're calling the pumpValid function before it's defined.

Comment: Hi, its there in pumpValid function. I believe I got the reason. Do I need to echo each line of Javascript? Leaving it outside PHP tags won't work?